# Who will receive the Monero tail emission

Tags: cryptonote, block-reward

After 18 million coins or by may 2022  the last block would be mined and tail emission follows. Thus, who will receive this tail emission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After 18 million coins or by may 2022 the last block would be mined

After ~18 million coins, the last pre-tail emission block will be mined. After this, all blocks mined will have a block reward of 0.6 Monero.

> Who will receive this tail emission?

The miners who mine the blocks.

Comment: Do you mean the Pool operators?

Comment: No. Only the miners will get any block rewards. Pool operators only get paid from the fees they charge for miners using their pool

Comment: samwellj - technically you have that backwards. Pool operators receive the block rewards for blocks their pools mine, and then pay out shares to the miners, who are essentially employees of the pools.